# Tell Android SDK Manager not to install HAXM

Tags: android, windows, hyper-v, android-sdk-manager

I'm trying to get Android Studio and React Native to play nicely. It's quite challenging. I'm using Windows 10 Pro with Hyper-V enabled, so I can't used HAXM. I've set up the emulator to use Hyper-V instead, and it's working.

Unfortunately, every single time I download a new SDK platform, SDK Manager insists it should install HAXM, so I spend a lot of time waiting for HAXM to be downloaded, then the installation starts and then it fails.

Is there any way to prevent SDK Manager from downloading and installing HAXM?

Comment: To be clear, are you referring to the SDK Manager in Android Studio, or the command-line version?

Comment: The one in Android Studio